# Misleading git message though the working tree is clean

Tags: git

Every time I update my local repository I push the changes to the remote master by running

`git add .`

`git commit -m "blablabla"`

`git push origin master`

Although I push the local changes, if I run git status I can see that my local branch is ahead.
This message is misleading as I have nothing to commit and I can see that the remote master matches the local when I visit the repo on Github.

Can anyone explain me why this message (your branch is ahead etc..) pops up if there's nothing to commit?
[image]

Comment: Read more carefully - you're ahead of `origin/main`, not `/master`. If you set up branch tracking correctly (i.e. to `master`, where you apparently want to push the changes, not `main`) you wouldn't need to explicitly set remote and branch to push to.

Comment: "Clean working dir" and "local branch is ahead of remote one" are two completely different and unrelated situations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I deleted the branch called "main" which was the default branch I got when I created the repo and kept dong my changes on the "master" branch I created at some point as I am more used to working with the repo named "master" .. is there a way to make git recognize the master as the new main ? thanks in advance @jonrsharpe

Comment: It's not clear what you mean _"recognize the master as the new main"_ - git itself doesn't care, what those branch names mean in your process is up to you.

Comment: at the beginning I used the default main but then I got rid and kept working on the master locally and pushing it to the master remotely .. I just would like git to understand that I deleted the main branch .. as this is no longer availble both locally and remotely. @jonsharpe

Answer (score 0):

You have a `master` branch and a `main` branch. When you do a commit, it is happening on the branch which is currently checked out, `master` in your case. But since there was some work performed and committed on the `main` branch as well, that particular branch is ahead of your `master` branch.

As a result, the response of `git status` is not misleading, but accurately informing you that you have this other branch where you have some commits that exist only at you locally. You could push all commits of all your branches via

```
git push --all origin
```

or you could

```
git checkout main
git push
```

to push only your commits on main.

But, before you do it, I advise you to check what these commits are and whether they should be pushed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I deleted the branch called "main" which was the default branch I got when I created the repo and kept dong my changes on the "master" branch I created at some point as I am more used to working with the repo named "master"  .. is there a way to make git recognize the master as the new main ? thanks in advance @Lajos Arpad

Comment: @Anjeline git treats all branches equally. Something else makes the difference in your case. Is it possible that you want your local branch to correspond to a remote main branch?

Comment: I also have a remote branch called master .. at the beginning I used the default main but then I got rid and kept working on the master locally and pushing it to the master remotely .. I just would like git to understand that I deleted the main branch .. as this is no longer availble both locally and remotely. @Lajos Arpad

Comment: @Anjeline if you run `git branch`, is the `main` branch listed?

Comment: no, it's not ..

Comment: @Anjeline what do you see if you run `git status`?

Comment: $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 22 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
@Lajos Arpad

Comment: @Anjeline what do you see if you run `git branch`?